# Installing Armadillo c++ library on windows

Tags: c++, windows, gcc, codeblocks, armadillo

I'm using windows 8, Code::Blocks IDE, and the gcc c++ compiler. 
I downloaded the latest version of Armadillo (4.550.0) and followed the instructions in the readme file, I copied the \include\ folder to my codeblocks project directory and added it to search directories in compiler settings.

However, when I attempt to compile one of the example programs from the armadillo download, I get the "No such file or directory" error.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you first try to compile an example on the command line and, once that works, then teach your IDE to do that. It is easier to give concrete advice that way.

Comment: I tried compiling with cmd and -l armadillo option, same thing: "fatal error: armadillo: No such file or directory compilation terminated."

Comment: You may need to add the -I option to tell gcc where to find the headers. For example: `g++ -I /path/to/include prog.cpp -o prog -O2`